# Ruby Cannot Determine Timezone From Nil (Argument Error)

Tags: ruby, null, timezone, rufus-scheduler, argument-error

I wrote some code with ruby. I get this error when I try to run the code:

```
/Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.3.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/zotime.rb:41:
  in `initialize':
  cannot determine timezone from nil (etz:nil,tnz:"+03",tzid:nil) (ArgumentError)
```

Edit:

I'm using ebooks gem. I only added consumer keys and access tokens. My .rb file is:

```
require 'twitter_ebooks'

class MyBot < Ebooks::Bot
  def configure
    self.consumer_key = 'Consumer Key'
    self.consumer_secret = 'Consumer Secret'
    self.blacklist = ['tnietzschequote']

    self.delay_range = 1..6
  end

  def on_startup
    scheduler.every '24h' do
    end
  end

  def on_message(dm)
  end

  def on_follow(user)
  end

  def on_mention(tweet)
  end

  def on_timeline(tweet)
  end

  def on_favorite(user, tweet)
  end

  def on_retweet(tweet)
  end
end

MyBot.new("twitter_id") do |bot|
  bot.access_token = "Access Token" # Token connecting the app to this account
  bot.access_token_secret = "Access Token Secret" 
end
```

I'll be glad if someone help me.

Comment: We're going to need some code to look at...

Comment: I added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting explicitly the `ENV['TZ']` before the scheduler instantiation

```
ENV['TZ'] = 'Asia/Shanghai' # your time zone 
  # or
ENV['TZ'] = Time.zone.tzinfo.identifier
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
# ...
```

should solve your issue :)

See https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#i-get-zotimerb41in-initialize-cannot-determine-timezone-from-nil

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the code?
I ran it and it worked fine for me.

```
mb = MyBot.new("twitter_id") do |bot|
  bot.access_token = "Access Token" # Token connecting the app to this account
  bot.access_token_secret = "Access Token Secret"
end

p mb.access_token
p mb.access_token_secret
```

Both of these yielded the appropriate values.

The error says there was an issue at line 41, but the code you posted isn't 41 lines. Maybe some more info could help...